# Support two versions of Today Widget ios 9/10

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I would like to know if it is possible and then how to support two versions of my Today Widget for iOS 9 and iOS 10 that appear only on the right OS.

So far I tried to have two targets one with a deployment target for iOS 9 and the other one for iOS 10. Unfortunately in the iOS 10 simulator both Today Widget appear.

Is there a way to do that or I need to handle it in my code with checks on what version I'm on ?

Comment: Shouldn't you be able to do this by [[NCWidgetController widgetController] setHasContent:NO forWidgetWithBundleIdentifier:YourTodayWidgetBundleIdentifier]; depending on your iOS version?

Comment: @Matt thank you for your comment, it kind of works. Actually the widget won't show up but it appears on the widget list.You could put your answer with more details and I will accept it.

Comment: You're welcome. I didn't have more to add so I just answered with the same thing. The reason I had posted a comment instead of an answer was because I hadn't tested it myself.

Comment: Is it possible to dynamically loaded a different storyboard based on iOS version? Having both show up isn't a great solution, especially if you know the iOS 9 version won't look great in iOS 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you cannot prevent your iOS 9 widget target from showing up in the widget choices list, you could set `hasContent` `false` on it and it will not show up in Today View by

```
[[NCWidgetController widgetController] setHasContent:NO forWidgetWithBundleIdentifier:YourTodayWidgetBundleIdentifier];
```

It's not a perfect solution but it can work.